# Convert tensor of floats to tensor fo integers inside loss function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a loss function, and I need to use the y_true and y_pred as indexes for a matrix which I'm using to calculate the loss. The problem is, both of these come as float tensors, and functions like cast() and round() are not differentiable, so I can't use them inside the loss functions.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from keras.utils import to_categorical

K = tf.keras.backend
A = np.random.randint(12, size=(12,12))


def score_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred)
    y_true = tf.nn.softmax(y_true)
    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred,"int32")
    y_true = K.cast(y_true,"int32")
    loss = -K.sum(tf.gather_nd(A, tf.stack((y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)))
    return loss

data = np.random.rand(1000,10)
data_y = np.array(range(0,10))
X = data[:, 0:8]
y = data[:, 9]
for i in range(0, len(y)):
  y[i] = data_y[i%9]
y = shuffle(y)
y = to_categorical(y, 9)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_shape = (8,), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(9, activation = "softmax"))
model.compile(loss = score_loss, optimizer= Adam())
```

Getting the following error during training:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

I need another way of making the conversion to integers or an alternative way of doing the whole thing.

Comment: At which line in the code is the error raised?

Comment: During the training when it calls the loss function.

Comment: Can you cast outside the loss function? If your model is producing indices, it might make more sense for them to be `int`s anyway.